# Elastic APM Intake API timeout except on python applications

Tags: elastic-stack, elk, apm, elastic-apm

I have an elastic apm server version `7.17.1`. There are only to Django application on the server. The APM service is using about 140MB of memory. When connecting new agents, I receive a timeout error.

node.js error

```json
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2022-07-07T23:15:34.033Z","log":{"logger":"elastic-apm-node"},"ecs":{"version":"1.6.0"},"message":"APM Server transport error: intake response timeout: APM server did not respond within 10s of gzip stream finish"}
```

Java error

> 2022-07-07 14:31:36,503 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR
> co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error
> sending data to APM server: Read timed out, response code is -1

If I use flask or Django or PHP, new apps are registered.

(I couldn't find logs from Go, but that APM agent failed as well.)

APM server logs did not appear relevant as the errors occurred in both instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your IPS. In our env, we saw the IPS swatting down packets from Java and Go-based apps. I'm no developer, but once we got those sources white-listed, we saw the Agents information coming through :)